# Scoped enum and std::get

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to use a scoped enum with a std::get to access an object stored in a std::vector

From Effective Modern C++ I'm using a version of Item 10 to cast the enum type to the underlying_type_t that can be used with std::get

```
template<typename E>
constexpr auto to_mytype(E enumerator) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(enumerator);
}
```

and

```
enum class my_type{sel_1, sel_2};
```

I have

`std::vector<std::variant<std::unique_ptr<option1>, std::unique_ptr<option2>> my_store;`

which is a member of my_class and I want to use the object stored in this vector like so

```
void my_class::my_function(const my_type selection)
{
    std::get<to_mytype(selection)>(my_store[i])->do_work();
}
```

where selection would be `sel_1` or `sel_2`. If I try this I get

```
error: selection is not a constant expression
```

Really I would like to store the type selected within the class and have the user only pass it once, to the constructor of my_class
to select whether an `option1` or `option2` object to be added to the vector.

Is there a way I can use an enum like this? I feel like I'm missing something quite simple.

Comment: This has nothing to do with enums and everything to do with not being able to use variables as non-type template arguments unless they're constants.

Comment: @Barry could you elaborate?

Comment: You can't do like... `void foo(int i) { std::array<int, i> values; }` This is the same kind of thing.

Comment: I see, this is due to the template being constexpr?

Comment: @Barry OK, thanks for your help

Comment: at all downvoters: this question is of high quality if you consider that it was asked by a new member. It shows some effort, and misunderstandings of how things work is not something that warrants downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with this code.

1. You try to use runtime index into std::get that requires compile
   time index
2. You are trying to select in std::variant, while variant does not hold multiple types at once(tuple does). Also note that variant already [knows](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) what type it currently holds.

As a bonus problem: IMAO tuple should be rarely used since it is quite ugly from readability perspective, struct with named members is usually much nicer.